# Why is $f(x) = 2x(x+3), x \in \mathbb{R^+_0}$, not surjective?

Tags: functions

$$f: [0, \infty]  \rightarrow [0, \infty)$$
If I claim that $f(x) = a, a \in \mathbb{R^+_0} $ and simplify the term I get that $$x = \pm \sqrt{\frac{a}{2} + \frac{9}{4}} -  \frac{3} {2}$$ From my understanding the negative solution falls away straight away because of the domain of x, but when I plug the positive term into f(x) I find that my claim is true, which would imply that my function is surjective. The solution states that it isn't surjective though.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Surjective... **on what**? If you don't state clearly domain and codomain it is impossible to solve questionslike this one.

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry, added the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is $0$ at $x=0$, diverges for $x\to \infty$ and is continuous.

By the intermediate value theorem, the function must be surjective.